# How can I scroll screen when the keyboard opened?

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, keyboard

I have an textview buttom of the view. But when the keyboard open, I can not see the textview. How can I scroll the view for see textview  when the keyboard open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 1):

[Read this Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1) which explains it all.

Especially the part "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard" explains the technique in details.

There is even extracts of code to implement this correctly (using Keyboard notifications).

[image: Adjusting content to accommodate the keyboard]
*Note that, as stated in the very same documentation, if you use an UITableViewController this will move its content automagically.*

Comment: thnx, but I want to ask a question. Should I put scroll view under the my view's textfileds??

Comment: You have to put all your content that needs to be scrolled (namely your UIView containing all your textfields) in a scrollview that embed this all. Of course if you have any "header" view on your that does not need to scroll, put it outside of the scrollview. _Well, to sum up, use this as you would use any other scrollview in your UI._

Comment: ok, I inserted a scrollview over my view and then I put all of my objects(label, button, textfield, textview) over this scrollview. I got some codes from this document but what is activeField ?

Comment: It is... the active field (did you read all the listings from the doc? It is explained in Listing 4-2...)

Comment: Ok sorry, now I see, How can I give and the keyboard size for scrolling? and where?

Comment: I mean that I use this methods, but not changing when click textview?

Comment: ... that's basic debugging. Of course you set your controller to be the delegate of all your textfields, right? And if it is textViews, you implemented the corresponding delegate methods (of UITextViewDelegate instead of UITextFieldDelegate as for Apple's example) and adapted your code accordingly of course?

Comment: I implemented exactly like this. - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    aciklama = textView;
    
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    aciklama = nil;
} and It should be like this? if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, aciklama.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, aciklama.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }

Comment: Ok this is unreadable in a comment and won't spend my whole day debugging your code (while you didn't even gave me points for what matters) go check your delegates and place breakpoints to debug your code first